# Return a concrete implementation in a list

Tags: list, interface, implementation, abstraction

I know this doesnt compile but why shouldnt it?

```
public interface IReportService {
  IList<IReport> GetAvailableReports();
  IReport GetReport(int id);
}

public class ReportService : IReportService {
 IList<IReport> GetAvailableReports() {
   return new List<ConcreteReport>(); // This doesnt work
 }

 IReport GetReport(int id){
   return new ConcreteReport(); // But this works
 }
}
```

Comment: you might want to add C# tag to get more answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because of [covariance](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rmbyers/archive/2005/02/16/375079.aspx). You can get it to work in .NET 4 (read the link).

Answer (score 0):

Try change to this

```
IList<? extends IReport> GetAvailableReports()
```

Answer (score 0):

I recently ran into this problem myself, and found that using IEnumerable instead of List solves the problem.  It was quite a frustrating issue, but once I found the source of the problem, it made sense.

Here's the test code I used to find the solution:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace InheritList.Test
{
    public interface IItem
    {
        string theItem;
    }

    public interface IList
    {
        IEnumerable<IItem> theItems; // previously has as list... didn't work.
                                     // when I changed to IEnumerable, it worked.
        public IItem returnTheItem();
        public IEnumerable<IItem> returnTheItemsAsList();
    }

    public class Item : IItem
    {
        string theItem;
    }

    public class List : IList
    {
        public IEnumerable<IItem> theItems; // List here didn't work - changed to IEnumerable

        public List()
        {
            this.theItems = returnTheItemsAsList();
        }
        public IItem returnTheItem()
        {
            return new Item();
        }

        public IEnumerable<IItem> returnTheItemsAsList()
        {
            var newList = new List<Item>();
            return newList;
        }
    }
}
```